# Rear gear change misses 1 gear

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, mechanical

Hi I have a 9 speed setup with the derailleur that springs to the largest cog.

My problem is that when I change through the gears one at time it misses 1 whole gear in the middle. It doesn't sit and "chatter" trying to change, it just jumps over 1. When I get to the smallest I still have one more shift on the shifter.

I am reasonably experienced at getting gears indexed and can normally get them right but this is driving me mad. the low screw is set just right and their is no slack on the cable when in the low gear. It changes fine the first 2/3 gears then misses one and carries on fine to the highest the same in reverse.
any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "springs to the largest cog" do you have a high normal derailleur? With the cable disconnected does the chain move to the largest or smallest gear when pedaled?. This would be unusual for a nine speed.

Comment: Hi, the chain moves to the largest gear when the cable is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly what is going on but I suspect the problem is in the cables and housing - either a routing problem or the cable is sticking.

Inspect the cable run and ensure there are no kinks and the housing is inserted in frame bosses properly.

Pull the cable out and clean it, lubricate and re-install (can be hard of the tip of the cable is frayed). Even better, replace cable and housing which is relatively inexpensive.

Re-adjust the derailleur. Start by rechecking the high and low limits. Start the indexing on the *smallest* sprocket - that way you know you won't have the problem of the derailleur arriving on the smallest sprocket with on click to go.

Comment: As @Argenti Apparatus has stated look at the cables pay particular attention where the cables enter and exit the outer housing. Inspect the cable with the derailleur on the largest and smallest sprocket. I have seen many cables kinked just outside the housing, especially when the top tube gets cinched down by a bike rack strap.

Comment: Also, before you do anything else, check your derailleur hanger alignment. Although it would be unusual for it to skip a gear with no “chatter” in the rest of the gears, it is possible.